# BigQuery: Why am I getting more rows after adding "LEFT JOIN"?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH rawData AS (
  SELECT
    wholesaler_id,
    month,
    day,
    year,
    product_volume,
    product_gp,
    buyer_id,
    salesrep_id AS default_salesrep_id,
    salesrep_name,
    fpl
  FROM tables.transactions
  WHERE wholesaler_id = 'hos'
  AND year IN (2019, 2018)
  AND month = 12
),
salesRepsToBuyersAssociation AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    default_salesrep_id AS salesrep_id,
    buyer_id
  FROM rawData
)
```

This query returns 60636 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM rawData
```

This query returns 72039 rows:

```
SELECT
  rawData.*,
  salesrep_id
FROM rawData
LEFT JOIN salesRepsToBuyersAssociation USING (buyer_id)
```

LEFT JOIN suppose to join only matching `salesRepsToBuyersAssociation` rows to `rawData`, right? Why on earth am I getting more rows than exist in the `rawData`?

Comment: If you want only matching rows, probably what you want is `INNER JOIN` no ?

Answer (score 6):

Because there are multiple rows in `salesRepsToBuyersAssociation` for one or more `buyer_id`s.

You can check this:

```
select buyer_id, count(*)
from salesRepsToBuyersAssociation
group by buyer_id
having count(*) > 1;
```